# datepart function not working in sql azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to split date part like year and assign it to a variable in a stored procedure.
I run that stored procedure in sql azure. it throws error "**Reference to database and/or server name in 'MASTER..spt_values' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.**"

Code:

```sql
declare @Year int
SET @Year =DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE())
create table #SundayDates (Sunday datetime,NextSunday datetime)
INSERT INTO #SundayDates(Sunday,NextSunday)
SELECT max(dates),MAX(DATEADD(DD,+7,dates)) AS last_sunday from
(
    SELECT dateadd(day,number-1,DATEADD(year,@year-1900,0)) AS dates
    FROM MASTER..spt_values WHERE type='p' and
    number between 1 and DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(year,@year-1900,0),DATEADD(year,@year-1900+1,0))
) as t
WHERE DATENAME(weekday,dates)='sunday' GROUP BY DATEADD(month,datediff(month,0,dates),0)
```

Comment: SET @Year =DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE()) INSERT INTO #SundayDates(Sunday,NextSunday)
 SELECT max(dates),MAX(DATEADD(DD,+7,dates)) AS last_sunday from
 (
 SELECT dateadd(day,number-1,DATEADD(year,@year-1900,0))
 AS dates FROM MASTER..spt_values
 WHERE type='p' and number between 1 and
 DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(year,@year-1900,0),DATEADD(year,@year-1900+1,0))
 ) as t
 WHERE DATENAME(weekday,dates)='sunday' 
 GROUP BY  DATEADD(month,datediff(month,0,dates),0)

Comment: Sounds like it's nothing to do with `DATEPART`, just that that function call happens to be near where the error is. But without seeing any code, it's a tad tricky to provide any help.

Comment: Please use the edit link below your question to add your code. You can then use the `{}` button to make sure it's formatted nicely.

Comment: Rather than giving us a horribly roundabout problem description, why not just ask for something that gives the last Sunday of each month of the current year, together with the date of the following sunday? That's a spec that's easier to work to.

Comment: Hi, One thing i observed is my db name is betopper by the error showing is Master. I dont know why..? Thank for the Help

Comment: Fine! I'll edit your question since you can't be bothered to. Look at your code. It *contains* the text `MASTER..spt_values`. Do you really think the issue is about `DATEPART` still?

Comment: I think the issue is not regarding datepart, may be due to change in db name.

Answer (score 0):

This query gives the same results (as a result set, rather than inserting into a temp table, but can be easily adapted to do so) and doesn't rely on the `spt_values` table that the error message **tells you** isn't allowed:

```sql
;With Numbers (Num) as (
    select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
    select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11
), MonthEnds as (
    select DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(year,'20010101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)*12 + n.Num,'20010131') as EndDate
    from Numbers n
), LastSundays as (
    select DATEADD(day,-n.Num,EndDate) as EndDate
    from
        MonthEnds me
            cross join
        Numbers n
    where
        n.Num between 0 and 6 and
        DATEPART(weekday,DATEADD(day,-n.Num,EndDate)) = DATEPART(weekday,'20130512')
)
select EndDate,DATEADD(day,7,EndDate) as FollowingSunday
from LastSundays
```